# pickle rpy2 objects in windows

Tags: pickle, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 V2.0.8 with Windows. I'm using rpy2 to for classification and would like to save (pickle) the model (for example the output from glm). However, as far as I know V2.0.8 does not support pickling rpy2 objects (and this is the latest version for Windows).
Do you have any suggestions how can I pickle / save the classification output in a file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of:

- find out why there is no Windows support and do something about it ;-)
- contribute windows support
- roll out your own solution using R's mechanism for serialization (which is what rpy2 >= 2.1.0 is doing)

Comment: Not necessarily. The information is in the documentation and on the mailing list. Note that point two can be done without asking me. ;-)